# Getting MemoryError when opening large Zip file around 1.5GB in python 3.7.4

Tags: python

I am running the following code to caluclate CRC32 of ZIP file

```
buf = open("C:\\users\\Raj\\temp\\ZIPs\\XXX.ZIP",'rb').read()
```

MemoryError

If i restart the machines it works fine and after running this command for multiple times i am getting the same error

This is the code i am using for caluclating CRC of ZIP file more than a 1.5 GB

```
zip_file=C:\\users\\Raj\\temp\\ZIPs\\XXX.ZIP"
buf = open(zip_file,'rb').read()
buf = (binascii.crc32(buf) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
(open(zip_file,'rb')).close()
```

Comment: `(open(zip_file,'rb')).close()` Oof. This one almost hurts physically. This opens the file and then immediately closes it again. It's completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the opened zip file. Try this:

```
zip_file="C:\\users\\Raj\\temp\\ZIPs\\XXX.ZIP"
with open(zip_file,'rb') as handle:
    buf = handle.read()
    buf = (binascii.crc32(buf) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I am still facing same issue.